# Why might a button work on desktop, but not on mobile?

Tags: javascript, mobile, background-image, mobile-safari

There are two buttons that I am having issues with:

The first is a burger button for my navigation menu.

Here is the javascript code for my burger button:

```
const burgerButton = document.getElementsByClassName('burger')[0]
const navLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-links')[0]

burgerButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

The button works perfect on PC, but doesn't do anything when clicked on mobile. However, for some reason, when I rotate my phone sideways into landscape mode, the button works fine.

I suspect that the issue may have something to do with the background image that is behind the button, since the burger button works perfectly fine on all of my other webpages (which do not have background images).

The second problem is with my website logo image, which has an anchor tag that takes the user back to my home screen. Just like the burger button, it works fine on all of my pages except for the page with a background image.

The background image spans the entire page, as I have set the background-size to cover and the height to 100vh. Additionally, I changed the z-index of both buttons to 10 in an effort to bring them in front of the background image. However, this did not fix the issue.

What are some reasons for the buttons not being clickable on mobile (in particular, in portrait mode)?

(By the way, I am testing in safari on an ios device. I'm not sure if that is important.)